# how to detect Number and Decimal Keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard, numpad

I'm developing a custom keyboard and based on Apple App Store Review guideline I have to provide a keypad for decimal and number pad :

```
Keyboard extensions must provide Number and Decimal keyboard types as described in the App Extension Programming Guide or they will be rejected
```

So I have to provide a keyboard for Decimal and Number Textfield, so how can I detect textfield type.

There is nothing about Number or Decimal Keyboard in [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html) so How detect which textfield I should load Decimal Keyboard or Number Keypad ?

Comment: What are you asking exactly? The sentence you quoted means that if you're developing a custom keyboard, you should provide a Number and Decimal keyboard. If you're developing an app with text fields, it's up to you to decide which keyboard to bring up on specific text fields.

Comment: @p4sh4 Yes, That's exactly what I'm asking, I'm developing a custom keyboard and you based on the quoted sentences I have to provide a keyboard for Decimal and Number Textfield, so how can I detect textfield type.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current keyboard type before your view appears like so (in Swift).

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Setup keyboard manager to correct type
        if let inputTraits = self.textDocumentProxy as? UITextInputTraits {
           let keyboardType = inputTraits.keyboardType
           let returnKeyType = inputTraits.returnKeyType
        }
    }
```

This from my project but reformatted for clarity. I also didn't compile it since it's such a simple example.

I've found it's good not to trust any extension API values until the view is visible or about to appear, but you could also try this in viewDidLoad()